# 404 not found when calling a Web Service from within another app in the test environment

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-services, iis, soap

I am trying to call a web service function from an app on the test environment. This works when I run it locally from the debugger but not in the test environment and am getting the following error:

**Error:**

The request failed with HTTP status 404: Not Found at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall) at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters) at APPNAME.DataService.DataService.Dummy() in C:\Users\username\Source\Repos\APPNAME\APPNAME\Web References\DataService\Reference.vb:line 154 at APPNAME.WebService1.Export(String name, String fileType, String geogOrGeom, Boolean geoView) in C:\Users\username\Source\Repos\APPNAME\APPNAME\WebService1.asmx.vb:line 2107

The paths in the error message are showing the paths from the local environment, not test. Why is that?

**Web service web.config:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="3600" />
    <compilation strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.7" />
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0" />
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*" />
        </authorization>
  </system.web>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.SqlServer.Types" publicKeyToken="89845dcd8080cc91" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-14.0.0.0" newVersion="14.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="DocumentFormat.OpenXml" publicKeyToken="8fb06cb64d019a17" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.11.0.0" newVersion="2.11.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

**Main app data service call (line 2107):**

```
Public WithEvents DS As New DataService.DataService

DS.Dummy()
```

**Web Service function being called:**

```
<WebMethod()>
    Public Function Dummy()
        My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("C:\Users\username\Desktop\Log.txt", "Dummy function reached. ", True)

        Return 0
    End Function
```

The web service is set up like every other working app in the test environment.
This is where the service path is located:

C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Test\Name\UserName\AppName

The service url is taken from a settings.xml file and is currently set to:

http://dvl.Name.co.uk/Test/NAME/UserName/AppName/dataservice.asmx

**IIS settings:**

[image: IIS settings:]

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Comment: The first thing to know is whether the 404 is caused by the application itself or the web service. You can directly enter the url that calls this service in the browser. If you can call it correctly, compare this url with the url requested by the application, and you may be able to find the cause of the 404.

Answer (score 0):

Check the URL carefully, most of the time it gives such an error.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I did not realise services are not supposed to go in the same folder as the app folder on the test server. (inetpub\root folder) instead the service needed to be put in the inetpub\internalServices folder. My problem has now been resolved, although I'm not sure how I could have figured this out without asking a colleague who already knew. Maybe someone can answer this here for future reference.